# node.js mocha test request

Tags: node.js, testing, tdd, express, mocha.js

I'm using mocha.js and supertest.js to test the requests of my json server on express.js. These are my imports:

```
request = require('supertest')
assert  = require('assert')  # Node assert
app     = require('../app')  # Vanilla express app
```

This is my request implementation in the express app:

```
app.get '/user/:id', (req, res) ->
  res.json {}
```

and this is my test:

```
describe 'GET /user/:id', ->
  it 'should return the user data if user found', (done) ->
  request(app)
    .get("/user/some_id")
    .end((err, res) ->
      assert.equal('test', 'test')
      done()
    )
```

This works, but if I change my request to:

```
app.get '/user/:id', (req, res) ->
  User.findById req.param('id'), (err, doc) ->
    res.json {}
```

the mocha test just times out. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the find is async and the test doesn't wait for it to finish. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to increase the timeout:

```
mocha --timeout 5000
```

The default is 2000 ms and might be too short. From the [documentation](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/).

Answer (score 1):

Switching to https://github.com/mikeal/request/ solved it. I'm now doing

This is my test now:

```
describe 'GET /user/:id', ->
  it 'should return the user data if user found', (done) ->
    request.get(
      'http://localhost:31000/user/500d365abb75e67d0c000006'  
      , (err, res, body) ->
        json = JSON.parse body
        assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200)
        assert.equal(json._id, '500d365abb75e67d0c000006')
        done()
    )
```

Everything is working as expected now, but I still want to know if it's possible to use supertest or vows for this.